# how to make time.mktime work consistently with datetime.fromtimestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, mktime

I am expecting the following code will return 0 but I get -3600, could someone explains why? and how to fix it? thanks

`import datetime
  import time
  ts = time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))
  print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).timetuple())`

Comment: What is your local time? Daylight savings?

Comment: yes, Daylight saving in London

Comment: If you're in daylight savings then you'd be an hour behind where you normally are (GMT), which is -3600 seconds. There is no error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.mktime` converts a time tuple ***in local time*** to seconds since the Epoch.  Since `time.gmtime(0)` returns GMT time tuple, and the conversion assumes it was in your local time, you see this discrepancy.

Comment: I guess time.mktime is not the right peer for time.gmtime and we should use calendar.timegm instead.